# JPA 2: How to use Map<String , Employee> in OneToMany Relationship between Entities

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, jpa, jpa-2.0

When I try to use Map in OneToMany Relationship between entities , I face the problem . When I try to insert the data in map there is following exception throw

`Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: null index column for collection` .

Please explain this exception and give me small example of using `Map<>` in relations.

Comment: Could you explain, why are you using `Map<String, String>` instead of a `Set<YourEntity>`?

Comment: actually i prepare my self for OCE-JPA certification.

Comment: Since when is a Map<String, String> a "relationship" ?

Comment: sorry its my mistake, in relationship its Map<String ,Entity> . please give me some small example how to use this , and insert element using Map<>.

Comment: when i try to use `@MapKey ` annotation the program is run and there is no need to add element in the Map , But what is the problem with `@MapKeyColumn ` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good explanation here:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Maps

For JPA2, I quote:

> JPA 2.0 allows for a Map where the key is not part of the target object to be persisted. The Map key can be any of the following:
>
> - A Basic value, stored in the target's table or join table.
> - An Embedded object, stored in the target's table or join table.
> - A foreign key to another Entity, stored in the target's table or join    table.